# How to define a macro which can access variables in source file?

Tags: c

My program needs some character convert array, in `char_convert.c`:

```
unsigned short gsm_to_ucs2[] = {
     '@',   0xa3,  '$',   0xa5,  0xe8,  0xe9,  0xf9,  0xec,
     ......
};
```

I want to define a macro which can access `gsm_to_ucs2` array:

```
#define GSM2UCS(i) gsm_to_ucs2[i]
```

If I define this macro in `char_convert.h`, I will also need to add the following line:

```
extern unsigned short gsm_to_ucs2[];
```

Or else the complier will complain `"'gsm_to_ucs2' undeclared"`.

Is there a better way to define a macro which can access variables in source file?

Comment: Why do you want to use a macro, what is wrong with simply writing the variable itself?

Comment: I want to define a marco which can convert one character set to another character set, so other source files can utilize it.

Comment: C source code cannot access different translation unit unless explicitly specified with `extern` keyword. That given, macro cannot access different source file unless explicitly specified with `extern` or `#include`. Either expose variable with `extern`, or make function instead of macro (implemented in file where array is intended to be visible).

Answer (score 2):

Macro is just text substitution.

If something doesn't make sense if you think about it in terms of text substitution, it doesn't make sense as a macro, either.

This is the case of your question. It doesn't make sense to write `gsm_to_ucs2[i]` in the header, since that variable belongs to the .c file. So it doesn't make sense to do this using a macro, either.

Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a compound literal for this instead of a variable

```
#define GSM_TO_UCS2                                         \
(unsigned short const[]){                                   \
     '@',   0xa3,  '$',   0xa5,  0xe8,  0xe9,  0xf9,  0xec, \
     ......                                                 \
}
```

Then use it as in `GSM_TO_UCS2[45]`.

Observe the `const` in the type, a thing that your probable missed also for your example with the variable. This is important to allow the compiler to optimize the array away if the index is a constant.

Compound literals are available in C since C99. If you don't have this, you could declare your variable as `static` and expose the definition (with the `const` type) in the header file.

Comment: ：“you could declare your variable as static and expose the definition (with the const type) in the header file”. Could you give a example? I am not very clear.

Comment: @NanXiao `static unsigned short`. Static global variables (and functions) are local to translation unit and won't conflict between units on linking stage. Without it, you'll get 'multiple definitions'-kind error.

Answer (score 1):

This is really ugly, but you could use the macro's token-pasting operator to select from a bank of macros for each case.

```
#define GSM_TO_UCS2_0 '@'
#define GSM_TO_UCS2_1 0xa3
#define GSM_TO_UCS2_2 '$'
#define GSM_TO_UCS2_3 0xa5
#define GSM_TO_UCS2_4 0xe8
#define GSM_TO_UCS2_5 0xe9
#define GSM_TO_UCS2_6 0xf9
#define GSM_TO_UCS2_7 0xec
//...

#define CAT(x,y) x ## y
#define GSM_TO_UCS2(x) CAT(GSM_TO_UCS2_, x)
```